# S3 to Swift middleware proxy

Tags: proxy, amazon-s3, cloud-storage

We have an application which is ready for *AWS S3 Storage*. Recently we had an requirement to write also on a *Swift Object Storage*. I know that Swift stack has an option to enable S3 compatibility but unfortunately this cannot be achieved on this server due political restrictions.

So I would like to use a simple proxy which converts a S3 request into an Swift one. Note that I dont own the destination server so the comunication would be like that:

```
File Upload --S3Protocol--> S3-SWIFT-PROXY --SwiftProtocol--> Swift Storage Destination
```

Trying to achive that, I've went through several options but I didn't manage to make it work.

For example, the [swift-plugin](https://github.com/rickerc/swift-plugin-s3) seems to be a solution to install on the Swift server but not act as a proxy middleware to just forward the request to a third swift server.

Another lib I've went through is [swiftproxy](https://github.com/bouncestorage/swiftproxy) which does exactly what I need in the oposite way: forward a swift requests to S3.

Is there any way to solve this without changing the application layer?

Answer (score 2):

There's [s3proxy](https://github.com/andrewgaul/s3proxy) which does what you want to do